# How can i send webrequest with multiple cookies?

Tags: authentication, cookies, webrequest, setcookie, c#-to-vb.net

I want to send webrequest in c# with two cookies(need for authentication);

**for Ex:**

```
cookie name : user ,value= username;
cookie name : password , value=9848jf7s7ejhd;
```

so if i send request with above two cookies that must need to provide authentication with server.

And also the other cookies which i will get in response of it should be automatically handled.

Please how can i get this?

Answer (score 0):

In .NET, you can send web request using **HttpWebRequest** class in which you can specify the cookies through **CookieContainer** property. The *CookieContainer* is a collection where you can add numerous **Cookie**.

For more information, please refer the following pages

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookiecontainer.aspx